# How to search messages by right clicking a sender on Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 11 and Silvermel theme.  Does anyone knows how to bring up the search message dialog by right clicking on the from "Email sender"?

Currently, what I do is to open a message from that sender, copy the email address, open the search messages diagram and pasting the email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to quickly search for messages by a sender when having opened a mail from him. This can be achieved using the Thunderbird addon "[Search for Sender](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/search-for-sender/)".

I hope that answers your question.